# Unexpected result after file upload

Tags: php, database, file-upload

This code is to update database. it updates everything even uploads image sucessfully but after image upload the whole page gets blank and only "Array()" is displayed at top. Why is that?

```
<?php
if(!isset($_GET["prid"])){
    header("Location: prjedit.php");
}
else {
    $prid = intval($_GET["prid"]);
    $sqlprj = "SELECT * FROM projects WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1";
    $statement = $db->prepare($sqlprj);
    $statement->execute(array($prid));
    $project = $statement->fetchObject();
    //submitted form
    if( (isset($_POST["title"])) && (isset($_POST["details"])) ) {
            $title = $_POST['title'];
            $desc = $_POST['descr'];
            $details = $_POST['details'];
            if(!empty($_FILES['image']['name'])) {
                //update image
                $file = basename($_FILES['image']['name']);
                $dir = "projects/";
                $target_path = $dir . basename($_FILES['image']['name']);
                $tempname = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
                if(!file_exists($target_path)) {
                        if(move_uploaded_file($tempname, $target_path)) {
                                $sqlimg = "UPDATE projects SET image = ? WHERE id = ?";
                                $statement = $db->prepare($sqlimg);
                                $statement->execute(array($file, $prid));
                                if($statement->rowCount() > 0) {
                                    try {
                                        chdir('./projects/');
                                        unlink($project->image);
                                        chdir('..'); 
                                    }
                                    catch (Exception $e) {
                                        $message = "Sorry image delete failed ";
                                        echo $e->getMessage();
                                    }   
                                } 
                                else {
                                    die ($db->errorInfo());
                                }
                        }
                        else {
                                $message = "Sorry Image update failed";
                        }
                            } 
                            else {
                                    $message = "Sorry this image already exists but text";
                            }
                }
            // update project texts
            $sqlupd = "UPDATE projects SET title = ?, descinfo = ?, details = ? WHERE id = ?";
            $statement = $db->prepare($sqlupd);
            $statement->execute(array($title, $desc, $details, $prid));
            if($statement->rowCount()) {
                    $message = " Saved successfully";
            }
            else {
                    die($db->errorInfo());
            }
        }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [`Pdo::codeInfo` documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php), it returns **an array**.
When you write `die($db->errorInfo());` it will try to display this array.

As suggested by the documentation itself, you could try `print_r($db->errorInfo()); die;` and see what happens.

Comment: Oh, thanks :) it's showing Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => )

Comment: Try displaying a different message from all your `die()` to see where your code fails. It is not a SQL error, are you sure you have mixed $_POST and $_GET variables? (I know it is possible, but not sure how does your form look like.)

Comment: Error comes from last update part where $sqlupd = "UPDATE projects SET title = ?, descinfo = ?, details = ? WHERE id = ?"; but it works fine if i don't upload the image.

Comment: Well, that is not an error. You do not have a line with this ID in your database. Try displaying this id and check manually in your database if there is an existing row.

Comment: Opps, i got it, saving  exactly the same info into the database in the same row gives result 0 rows affected and my code was doing the same if new image is not selected for the update :)